# Form Partial works on index, not in global nav

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-6

I appreciate help with this issue. I have been a bunch and trying different options but to no avail.

I have tasks folder with an index and a form partial that I render on the tasks/index page <%= render"form_tasks" %>. When I submit a task on the index page, everything works fine and the task gets added. I have also included the form partial on a global modal that displays from the nav <%= "tasks/form_tasks" %>. the idea being I want to be able to add a task no matter where you are on the site. Except, if I am anywhere on the site outside of the /tasks folder, I get an error.

```
ActionController::ParameterMissing in TasksController#create

param is missing or the value is empty: tasks

def tasks_params
    params.require(:tasks).permit(:task, :details)
end
```

in my tasks controller I have

```
def create
    @task = tasks.new(tasks_params)
      if @task.save
        flash[:notice] = "Task Recorded"
        redirect_to task_index_path
      end
  end

private

  def tasks_params
    params.require(:tasks).permit(:task, :details)
  end
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `@task` is not available globally.  If you want that to be the case you should add it to your appliciation controller and set it in a `before_action` or something.  To be specific, `@task` is only set in your `tasks_controller`, any controller handling other views will not have access to it because of that, since everything inherits from application controller (most likely) if you add it there it there and set it in a `before_action` then every controller will have access to it..

Comment: Hi Rockwell, thank you for the response. That worked!